# How to search/filter by image source?

Tags: jquery, image, list, search, filter

I'm trying to make a page where I can filter by the source name of the image.

I found this script but it's only working on text: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/

Fiddle: jsfi ddle.net/sVJRk/

What do I need to filter by image source? See: jsfi ddle.net/sVJRk/1/

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question asked in the title, the [`attribute contains selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) is what you're looking for:

`$('img[src*="sport"]')`

Which would select all `images`, where the `src` property contains `sport`.

---

As for your question specifically, there are a number of issues:

1. You're passing `$('#list')` to the `listFilter` function, you don't have an element with that `id`.
2. You're then calling `$(list)` within your function body, you've already passed `list` as a jQuery object, so there's no need to wrap it again.
3. You're looking for `anchors` which contain the given string, but you don't have any `anchors` within your list (you have `images`).
4. There's no need for the custom `:Contains` selector if you only need to check if a string is contained within the `src` of  the `image` (you can use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)).

#### [Here's a working fiddle with the above changes](http://jsfiddle.net/sVJRk/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery contains filter is the answer you're looking for.
A light version can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/artuc/vTQq3/

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
$('.imageList img').not('[src*="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide();
$('.imageList img[src*="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
});
```